# Codeception + Selenium server + Centos+ BitrixVM5

Tags: centos, битрикс, selenium, codeception

Добрый день коллеги.
Использую тестовый сервер BitrixVM5 используется Centos 6.5
Вот установил Codeception, пытаюсь установить Selenium server, но команда в консоли типа java -jar selenium-server-standalone-2.xx.xxx.jar не срабатывает.

Как мне поставить Selenium server на Centos.
Нашел статью http://artursabirov.ru/dev/2011/08/20/selenium-server/ но не удается проделать до конца описанное, не могу понять куда деть этот код - https://i.stack.imgur.com/RqcRT.png,  да и при установки firefox ссылка 
-wget http://mirror.informatik.uni-mannheim.de/pub/mirrors/mozilla.org/firefox/releases/6.0/linux-i686/en-US/firefox-6.0.tar.bz2 (скриншот https://i.stack.imgur.com/gikdS.png)
 не работает, т.е не удается скачать по ссылке.

Установил java на сервер вот как описано вот тут - https://www.java.com/ru/download/help/linux_x64_install.xml
Вот куда установилось на сервере - https://i.stack.imgur.com/ui0on.png

Вот сама консоль - https://i.stack.imgur.com/2I6Gk.png

Подскажите пож. решить задачу.

Заранее спасибо.

Comment: Вы уверены, что вам прямо сейчас надо гонять системные тесты на внешнем серваке?

Comment: Не очень понял ваш вопрос.  А когда нужно их гонять ?

Comment: Внедрение всегда начинается на девелоперской машине в отдельном окружении, но никак не на продакшене. Тесты с реальным участием фаерфокса - либо ci-сервер, либо машина девелопера, но нагружать этим продакшен-сервак - это ээээээ очень сильно не нужно. Вообще для простых тестов хватит и phantomjs, запущенного в режиме вебдрайвера.

Answer (score 1):

Для того чтобы не мучиться с установкой Selenium на сервере используйте phantomjs.

Подробная статья по установке Selenium на сервере http://habrahabr.ru/post/239645/